# ことか to place strong emphasis on something?

Tags: meaning

According to this website (http://www.jlptsensei.com/grammar-lesson/kotoka/)
"ことか is used to place strong emphasis on something." This is the only explanation I could find. I was wondering if that is a common expression  and in what context would you use it? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The ことか is used in an exclamatory sentence (感嘆文) , usually preceded by an interrogative word such as どんなに, どれほど, なんと, 何度 etc.

Examples:

> - **どんなに**うれしい**ことか**！ (≂ どんなにうれしいだろう！)
>     How happy I would be!
> - **なんと**美しい**ことか**！ (≂ なんと美しいのだろう！ / なんて美しいんだろう！)
>     How beautiful it is!
> - **何度**失敗した**ことか**！ (≂ 何度失敗しただろう！)
>     (I have no idea) How many times I have failed!

(「～～ことか！」 sounds a bit more literary than 「～～だろう！」)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. なんということか！
>      What the hell (is this) !
> 2. ずっと一緒だった仲間が別れなければならないのは、なんと残念なことか。
>      Having to say farewell to friends that were always with you is so sad.
>      ([Source](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=kotoka))

> 3. コンピューターは、なんと便利なことか。
>      Computer is such a convenient thing.
>      ([Source](http://for2kyu.blogspot.com/2009/04/159.html))

As I know. ことか is a 2kyuu grammar. It is used to express your feeling about....

Comment: Could you provide the source(s) of your example sentences, please?