# using か with a verb

Tags: particle-か

When attaching か to a verb, for example: 食べるか, it can mean "as if it can be eaten". Or 知るか to mean "as if I know". From what I know about か, it really only a question mark, so how does it get translated to "as if"? Also, if I use か in this manner, will I be considered a ブレもの?

Comment: @Mindful The か usage I was asking does not relate to an embedded question. It is more along the times of 知るか、そんなもん which translates to "As if I know, that kind of thing"

Comment: Ah, this would be much clearer with some context, but I see now. I deleted my previous comment. You're asking about the rhetorical usage of か.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72376/%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b-and-variant-phrases

Comment: What is ブレもの? I don't know such a Japanese word...

Comment: @naruto I thought it meant rude, must have spelt/ pronounced it wrongly

Comment: @naruto 無礼者だと思います